# How to use swing timer for sleep in for loop?

Tags: java, swing, timer

How to use swing timer for sleep in for loop?

for (int j = 0; j < 0; i++) {
        System.out.println(j);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //
        }
    }

Comment: lol, negative points for what

Comment: How is that a swing timer? Otherwise...looks like you got it figured out.

Answer (score 2):

I think this question is receiving negative votes because:

- It is unclear what the context of the problem is and/or what you are trying to do
- You have not listed what you've tried before posting
- Google could probably answer your question

But in the spirit of helpfulness:

I consulted Google to find this resource on the Java swing Timer: http://supportweb.cs.bham.ac.uk/documentation/java/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html

I am not Java expert, but I would suggest trying:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 0; i++) {
  System.out.println(j);
  timer = new Timer(ONE_SECOND, new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
           //...Whatever you are trying too do (ie. update progress bar)
              if (/* What you are waiting for */) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                     //
                    }
              }
         }    
     });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `for` loop has two syntax issues

```
for (int j = 0; j < 0; i++) {
```

you are comparing `j < 0` (and given that the initial value of `j` is `0`, your loop will never be entered) and you are incrementing `i` instead of `j`. Assuming your loop was intended to print the numbers `0` to `9` at one second intervals you could do so with a `Timer` and an `ActionListener`. Starting with the listener, initialize a counter and keep a local reference to the `Timer` (so the Listener can stop the Timer). Something like

```
static class MyListener implements ActionListener {
    int n = 0;
    Timer t;

    public void setTimer(Timer t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (n < 10) {
            System.out.println(n++);
        } else {
            // Stop the Timer
            t.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Next, we need to create a `Timer`; initialize the `Listener`, and `start` (waiting for the process to complete). Something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyListener mm = new MyListener();
    try {
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Timer t = new Timer(1000, mm);
                mm.setTimer(t);
                t.start();
            }
        });
    } catch (InvocationTargetException | InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```